# Unable to submit in contact us (magento 1.7 )

Tags: php, magento, contact-form, magento-1.7

I'm not being able to send emails in contact us magento 1.7 and i always have the following error knowing that i have the hideit input available

```
    <div class="buttons-set">
    <p class="required"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
    <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
    <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?>"           class="button"><label><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></label></button>
     </div>
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the "hideit" input added, then make sure you've got this commented out:

```
if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post[’hideit’]), ‘NotEmpty’)) { 
$error = true; 
}
```

inside app/code/core/Mage/contacts/controllers/indexController.php

and be sure that you edit right form.phtml!

As per: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/84843/

Answer (score 3):

Most of the answers to this question involve responses that involve hacks.
As we want our site to be easily upgradable, we attempt to stay away from hacks.
The answer for us on version 1.6.2 was to remove the second email address from the email address field in configuration for the "contact us" details and error went away.

Comment: could you please give your answer step by step.I am facing the same problem.And I am not getting where to make changes. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the exact identical string for contact en store mail addresses.
I had a mix of capitals and subs after setting everything in in subs it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The solution described by "Ethan" is best one.You must check the configurations at the back end you made for the  contact information .You should also check the email addresses 
used.

1)Go to System -> Configuration->General->contacts  under "Send Emails To" fill the email like xyz@example.com.

2)See the email sender example "Custom Email 2".

3)Now go to System -> Configuration->Store email Addresses.Then under "custom email2" fill the same email address i.e "xyz@example.com."

Final most thing if you are using Localhost.You must have a SMTP server installed to check the emails received.

Answer (score 0):

I Get Solution form Magento 1.9

1. Check if you maybe missed configuration settings for enabling email sending functionalities.

2.Try to change “Sending emails to” to some other email which do not have same email domain as your Magento website.
 Some hosts can produce problem if “Sending from” email is from same host provider as the “Sending to” email.

3.Create new transaction email your magento site domain for Contact form transactional email and name it differently than default.as
Go to System -> Configuration->General->contacts under "Send Emails To" fill the email like xyz@domain.com.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question, but I have had the same problem. One of the ways to solve this is go to Configuration > Advanced > System > Mail Sending Settings

Set Disable Email Communications to No